# Use CSS to hide non-anchor elements

Tags: html, css

I have a container that looks like this

```
<div id="container">This container has a <a href="#">link</a> in it</div>
```

I want to hide everything in it except the link.

I've tried

```
#container {display:none;} 
#container a { display:block; }
```

But that doesn't work.

It's a user style, so I have access only to the CSS. No Javascript. No markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `visibility` will work here if you don't mind the invisible, non-linked text still taking up space.

```
#container {
 visibility: hidden;  
}
#container a {
 visibility:visible;  
}
```

And if you do need to mimic the display block style, you can try:

```
#container {
 visibility: hidden;   
 position: relative;
}
#container a {
 visibility:visible;  
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Best suggestion so far. I adjusted the font-size in #container to 0%. Good enough for this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible with the code you’re currently using. Because the text fragments are text nodes that are only represented by [anonymous inline boxes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#anonymous) that can not be styled with `display` separately.

But if you put the text that’s surrounding the `a` element also in elements, e.g. `span`s:

```
<div id="container"><span>This container has a </span><a href="#">link</a><span> in it</span></div>
```

Then you can do this:

```
#container span { display: none; }
#container a { display: block; }
```

Comment: Extra markup won't work here as the OP does not have access to the page.

Comment: That looks right. But since this is for a user style, I don't have access to the markup. Thanks, though.

Comment: @Morten J: It depends on what you’re trying to do if your efforts will be successful.